# How to get back valid JSON from mysql column where a javascript object is stored

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, angular

I have some data I need to store inside a mysql table. The table has a few columns, among them a `book` and `authors` column, both of which are TEXT fields. I need to store a javascript object in the book column and an array of objects in the authors column.

Inside my angular component, I have the book object and authors array of objects.

```
const book = {
   title: "hello world",
   subtitle: "learn C programming in a week",
   cover: "path/to/cover.png"
};

const authors = [{id: 3, name: "John Doe"}, {id: 4, name: "Jane Doe"}];
```

The object I'm passing to my service to handle the post request looks something like the following.

```
{
   id: this.generateId(),
   category: this.category,
   book: JSON.stringify(book),
   authors: JSON.stringify(authors),
   price: this.price
}
```

Both of these are being stringified via `JSON.stringify(...)` and then successfully being posted to the database. No problem there.
I should also mention that the object values are being grabbed and put into an SQL statement in the POST request like so...

```
`INSERT INTO library (id, category, book, authors)
 VALUES ('${obj['id']}',
              '${obj['category']}',
              '${obj['book']}',
              '${obj['authors']}')`
```

However, when I try to retrieve data from that table via my angular service, angular throws the error `Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/`.

When I fire the same request via `postman`, I get back the data but then when I check the validity of the returned JSON, it's not valid. The returned data looks something like this...
The `title"` gets highlighted with the error `Expecting comma, colon or }, not string`

```
[
  {
    "book": "{
      "title": "hello world",
      "subtitle": "learn C programming in a week",
      "cover": "path/to/cover.png"
    }",
    "authors": "[{"id": "3", "name": "John Doe"}, {"id": "4", "name": "Jane Doe"}]"
  }
]
```

What am I missing? How do I get back valid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

"book": "{ - this looks like you have stringyfied the two values separately and then added to one object?

If so create one object first and stringify the entire thing.

Comment: That is exactly the case. I've made an edit to reflect the same. Let me try stringifying the entire object.

Comment: That doesn't work. MySQL complains `ncorrect integer value: 'undefined' for column 'price' at row 1"` regardless of the value.

Comment: There is so much wrong with what you are doing to be honest I am not sure where to begin.
1) Why not create a link table for the authors and categories.
2) Why are you objectifying the book instead of just adding the fields into the database - you only seem to have 3 static and common fields - title, subtitle,cover
3) Do not insert into a database by using concatenated strings, use parameters and the driver.
4) You are passing in an object that you have nested stringifies on, book is still a string as far as the parser is concerned, same for authors.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the problem. I realize it doesn't look pretty as is lol. Try and ignore the glaring anti patterns. You do make some valid points though. I'l look further into it. Thank you.